# Using SSD as system drive for OS X, but using harddrive for data Users drive

Tags: mac, laptop, hard-drive, ssd

I'm trying to get the goodness of SSD drive, while still being able to have lots of storage...

My current Mac laptop does not support it, but suppose that it does (or suppose that I buy a hybrid drive). How do I mount the system and application data in my SSD and keeping everything in my /Users folder in the hard drive? Do I need to do a clean install for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is absolutely possible. The best guide I've read about this is at [Lnx2Mac's Blog](http://lnx2mac.blogspot.com/2010/09/moving-os-x-users-to-separate-partition.html). You shouldn't need a clean install for this.

The best course of action would be to clone your current OS X hard drive to your new SSD if everything fits and then boot from your SSD to ensure that it works. Install your old drive as a secondary drive and then follow the instructions in the above link.

An expensive way of installing the secondary hard drive is using the [MCE Optibay](http://www.mcetech.com/optibay/). Also consider achieving the same function using a [DIY method](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=680228).

Comment: Wow that is quite a hacky way to do it... But I guess I'll do this later when I have some time, but this really really help. Thanks!